# History behind Daridraya Dukha Dahana Shiva Stotram?

Tags: shiva, history, identification-request, stotra

I was listening to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sQVm-Z7edE&feature=youtu.be) stotram on YouTube. Wanted to know more about it!

For knowledge sake just wanted to know some facts about it for instance:

1. Who wrote it and when?
2. What was the prime reason behind writing this stotram?
3. Any other important known facts worth sharing.

Answer (score 3):

As per all websites or books that contain this Stotra, it was composed by Rishi Vashishta.

The [Phalasruti](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Daridrya_Dahana_Shiva_Stotram) mentions this:

> **Vasishtena Krutham stotram**,
>  Sarva sampathkaram param,
>  Trisandhyam ya padenithyam,
>  Sa hi swargamavapnyuth.
>
> **This prayer composed by sage Vasishta**, Is one which gives all types of wealth, And whoever chants it at dawn, noon and dusk, Would
> enjoy the pleasures of heaven.

Another [website (Stutimandala)](http://www.stutimandal.com/poemgen.php?id=78) also mentions the same Phalasruti given above (from Hindupedia):

> Those who daily study this eulogy **written by Vasiṣṭha** — which
> destroys all the health-related problems, which brings wealth quickly,
> and which increments the lineage — indeed approach the heavens.[9]

[Note: I have only answered one of your many questions. So, it is a partial answer. I do not know the other answers like when it was composed and what were the reasons behind the composition etc.]